# Как правильно сформировать ответ сервера. (Яндекс карты)

Tags: node.js, yandex-maps-api, mongodb

Нужно вывести большое количество объектов на Яндекс картах. 
Попробовал использовать [LoadingObjectManager](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/loading-object-manager/about-docpage/). 

Приходит запрос с со стороны клиента в виде 
bbox=55.3589,36.2109,56.1519,39.0234&callback=myCallback_55_3589_36_2109_56_1519_39_0234 

 (Координаты противоположных углов видимой карты)


Я не могу правильно сформировать ответ сервера используя node.js и mongodb. 

Как правильно сформировать JSON описание объектов? 
Как обернуть JSON описание в callback функцию?
И как это отправить клиенту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации LOM есть пример как должен выглядеть ответ https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/loading-object-manager/about-docpage/ .

Здесь есть пример как написать сервер для ROM https://github.com/dimik/ymaps/tree/master/remote-object-manager-server для LOM он будет практически таким же.

Здесь про базовое Node.JS приложение с использованием express
https://habr.com/post/207930/